# how to create amcharts with multiple nested json objects

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, amcharts

Hello I'm using amcharts, i want to creat amchart using dataloader plugin, api response  having nested object. I tried it, but it wont work.
My json response in like this. Also i want to convert 24hrs time to 12 hrs time (Slot in json)
How do i create chart using this type of json using dataloader plugin
 
   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48gbap0x/4/)

```
         {
        "driver_data": [
            {
                "slot": 0,
                "rideCount": 0
            },
            {
                "slot": 30,
                "rideCount": 0
            },
            {
                "slot": 100,
                "rideCount": 0
            },
            {
                "slot": 130,
                "rideCount": 0
            },
            {
                "slot": 200,
                "rideCount": 0
            }
        ],
        "passenger_data": [
            {
                "slot": 0,
                "rideCount": 0
            },
            {
                "slot": 30,
                "rideCount": 0
            },
            {
                "slot": 100,
                "rideCount": 0
            },
            {
                "slot": 130,
                "rideCount": 0
            },
            {
                "slot": 200,
                "rideCount": 0
            },
            {
                "slot": 230,
                "rideCount": 0
            },

        ]
    }
```

Comment: Any clue on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI - AmCharts does not support nested JSON data. You need to convert it first.

First thing you need to do is actually include the `dataloader.min.js` file. The dataLoader is an external plugin, just like export, so it requires a separate include.

`<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>`

Second, make sure you have CSS set on your chart div. You don't have any in your fiddle.

```
#ridecounts {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Lastely, you need to use a [`postProcess`](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader/#user-content-complete-list-of-available-dataloader-settings) callback in your dataLoader to create a compatible JSON format - a single flattened array grouped by your `categoryField`. Since you named your `valueField` properties based on the array key names, make those your `valueField` when you reformat your data into an array of objects

```
dataLoader: {
    url: "...",
    // ...
    postProcess: function(jsonResponse, dataLoaderConfig, chart) {
      var categoryField = chart.categoryField;
      var newData = [];
      var groupedData = {};
      Object.keys(jsonResponse).forEach(function(arrayKey) {
        jsonResponse[arrayKey].forEach(function(dataItem) {
          if (!groupedData[dataItem[categoryField]]) {
            groupedData[dataItem[categoryField]] = {};
            groupedData[dataItem[categoryField]][categoryField] =
              dataItem[categoryField];
          }
          groupedData[dataItem[categoryField]][arrayKey] = dataItem.rideCount;
        });
      });
      Object.keys(groupedData).forEach(function(groupedKey) {
        newData.push(groupedData[groupedKey]);
      });
      return newData; //returns [{slot: 0, driver_data: 0, passenger_data: 0}, ...]
    }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/7338de7f33a2795e1d994b6b1175501a).

I'm not sure what you mean by converting 12/24 hour format as your data is not datetime based.

Comment: Thanks
As you saw slot it is actually time which shows now 0, 30, 100 want to convert it as12 am, 12:30 am, 01:00 am

Comment: AmCharts can't convert that. Why can't you return an explicit timestamp from your server instead of awkward integer values? Choosing a proper datatype/format will save you much more time than writing custom logic on top of a non-standard data format.

Comment: slot as of now shows as 0 30 100 130 200 230 .... But i want to show as 0 0:30 1:00 1:30 2:00 2:30 ....

Comment: I still think you should change your data but look into the categoryAxis [`labelFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#labelFunction).The first parameter you get is the slot value. Use whatever string manipulation you need to get your desired result.

Comment: I tried but not working, could you explain me how to use it using existing example 
Check this
http://jsfiddle.net/v0jkx9of/

Comment: Did you read the docs? 1) It's called **`labelFunction`**, not categoryFunction. 2) Not sure why you're trying to access a date property in dataItem when there isn't one - your data does not contain dates.You want the first parameter like I said. Regex/string replace/whatever you want to format the first parameter. I updated the [codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/7338de7f33a2795e1d994b6b1175501a).

Comment: Oh, it's my bad.
Thanks

Comment: It works, but having some issues with some values pls check attached 
https://github.com/vishaalmandge/FD/blob/master/1.PNG
https://github.com/vishaalmandge/FD/blob/master/2.PNG

I tried but it wont work
if (valueText.length < 3 && valueText.length < 4){
                    return valueText;
                } else {
                    return valueText.replace(/(0|30)/, ":$1");
                }

Comment: Fixed. I still think you should fix your data instead of using a labelFunction.

Comment: Yes I did. Look at the line with replace.

Comment: how we plot y-axis from JSON object, highest value should be max & lowest value should be min.