# How to create chart with dynamic y-axis, depends upon highest values in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, amcharts

Can anybody know how to create chart with dynamic y-axis, that depends upon highest values in JSON? I tried to find, but I didn't get any solution even in amCharts docs as well.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h04b3dgq/1)

Json Format

```
{
        "driver_data": [
            {
                "slot": 0,
                "rideCount": 10
            },
            {
                "slot": 30,
                "rideCount": 20
            },
            {
                "slot": 100,
                "rideCount": 60
            }
        ],
        "passenger_data": [
            {
                "slot": 0,
                "rideCount": 3
            },
            {
                "slot": 30,
                "rideCount": 10
            },
            {
                "slot": 100,
                "rideCount": 80
            },

        ]
    }
```

Comment: Any clue on this??

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic y-axis? Can you talk about what you would like to do, and how you expect the chart to behave? Also while we're at it, is there a specific version of amCharts you're using?

Comment: I'm using amcharts v3. My requirement is. I'm calling ajax API & I get the response in JSON format. Eg. I have counts on y-axis & dates on the x-axis.
Dates from 1st Jan to 10th Jan & counts like 10, 30, 56, 90 etc..then highest value of count is 90 then it will show 0 to 90 on the y-axis

Comment: @notacouch pls check above comment

Comment: @Jon your question should include your current code and what you've done/tried so far. Please add this so we can help you.

Comment: @xorspark
Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h04b3dgq/1, here you'll find sample json. 
you can update the solution of this question which you gave https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327925/how-to-create-amcharts-with-multiple-nested-json-objects

Comment: This needs to be in your question, not in a comment. See the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Comment: @xorspark Question updated, pls check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dataLoader's [`complete` callback](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader/#user-content-using-callback-functions) to take your procssed JSON in your dataProvider and update the chart's valueAxes' `maximum` property based on the largest value in the stack. For example:

```
    complete: function(chart) {
      //get valueFields
      var valueFields = chart.graphs.map(function(graph) {
        return graph.valueField;
      });
      //find the maximum stack in each category
      var maxValue = chart.dataProvider.reduce(function(maxValue, dataItem) { 
        var sum = valueFields.reduce(function(sum, valueField) {
          return sum + dataItem[valueField];
        }, 0);
        return Math.max(maxValue, sum);
      }, Number.MIN_VALUE);
      //update each value axis' maximum and set strictMinMax to true
      chart.valueAxes.forEach(function(valueAxis) {
        valueAxis.maximum = maxValue;
        valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
      });
      //update chart
      chart.validateData();
    }
  },
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/db6ad3bbb645d148a5da7b9df45e9e3b?editors=0010)

Comment: how we use "complete" without dataloader, pls check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qvbsf3j9/2/ where value is passed (Textbox value) through body of api

Comment: I got the answer

Comment: I want to know how we do chart container width dynamic based on no.of columns on x-axis

Comment: @Jon - this is all a separate SO question. I'm not answering follow ups in comments from previously accepted answers to old questions.

Comment: new question created pls check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589764/charts-container-width-height-dynamic-in-amcharts