# Charts container width & height dynamic in amcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, amcharts

I'm using amcharts & i want chart container width & height dynamic depending on no columns on x-axis & highest value in y-axis in amcharts. Here is my fiddle 
I use css as follows

```
    .graphsdata {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.graph-div {
    min-width: 800px;
    min-height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.graphs-div {
    width: 2200px;
    min-height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[check this](http://jsfiddle.net/4g9pwcr8/)

Comment: For resizing your chart based on your category axis, see [this example](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/dynamically-resizing-chart-container-per-number-columnsbars/). It uses the height but the idea is similar enough to adapt for width. You need to clarify how you're sizing the height though for your value axis.

Comment: @xorspark, no its not working,
http://jsfiddle.net/qvbsf3j9/7/

Comment: Look at the example again and compare against your code. The initHandler is looking for a `resizeCategoryWidth` property in your chart config before attempting to run the rest of the code. Your fiddle doesn't set this value. Also don't include credit removing code in public fiddles.

Comment: What change should i do, dint understand, could you pls help me out in this?

Comment: Add `resizeCategoryWidth` to your makeChart call. Set it to a value that you deem reasonable. It's in the example I linked. You also need to remove `min-width` on your chart div or it won't work. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qvbsf3j9/9/). I added a comment at line 44 in your JS highlighting the property.

Comment: It's working, Thanks man